# Prove that $b(c+a)<\sqrt{2}$ for $a^2+b^2+c^2-a(b+c)=2-\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers with $a^2+b^2+c^2-a(b+c)=2-\sqrt{2}$. Prove that $b(c+a)<\sqrt{2}$.

I've tried a lot of ways to use AM-GM on the inequality and to try to prove equivalent inequalities but I can't be able to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: A peanut (ellipsoid) between two crushing walls (hyperbolic cylinder). How comfortable are you with quadric surfaces?

Comment: @CatalinZara Was looking for a more elementary proof, but if it works then sure!

Comment: Change coordinates to get one of the conditions in a more standard form. Try a linear change of variables (such as $a=\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z$, and so on for $b$ and $c$) that would eliminate the $ab$, $ac$, and $bc$ terms in one of the conditions.

Comment: @CatalinZara Do you have any tips on finding such transformations?

Comment: Use the following fact. $ax^2+bx+c\geq0$, where $a\neq0$, for any real $x$ iff $a>0$ and $b^2-4ac\leq0.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks! Can you explain how to use this here, please?

Answer (score 1):

Say we have $B$ a [positive definite](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html) matrix and $A$ and [symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) ( of same size). Now we want the maximal and the minimal values of

$$v \mapsto \frac{\langle A v, v \rangle } {\langle B v, v\rangle }$$

In many cases one treats the case $B = I$, the identity matrix. However, we can reduce to this case in this way. Write

$$\langle B v, v\rangle = \langle B^{\frac{1}{2}} v, B^{\frac{1}{2}} v\rangle  = \langle w,  w \rangle \\
\langle A v, v\rangle  = \langle A B^{-\frac{1}{2}} w, B^{-\frac{1}{2}} w\rangle =\langle B^{-\frac{1}{2}} A B^{-\frac{1}{2}} w,  w\rangle $$
so
$$\max \frac{\langle A v, v \rangle } {\langle B v, v\rangle } = \max \frac{\langle B^{-\frac{1}{2}} A B^{-\frac{1}{2}} w,  w\rangle}{\langle w, w \rangle} $$

and that equals the largest of the eigenvalues  of $B^{-\frac{1}{2}} A B^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, that is, the largest of the root of the polynomial

$$\det(t I- B^{-\frac{1}{2}} A B^{-\frac{1}{2}}) = \det B^{-1}\det ( t B - A)$$

Now in our case we have

\begin{eqnarray}
b(a+c)&=& (a,b,c) \cdot A \cdot (a,b,c)^t\\
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -a(b+c) &=& (a,b,c) \cdot B \cdot (a,b,c)^t
\end{eqnarray}

where
\begin{eqnarray} 
A &=& \left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \\
B &=& \left ( \begin{matrix}1&-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}& 1& 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) 
\end{eqnarray}

Now we have
$$\det ( t B - A) = \frac{1}{2}  t^3 - \frac{3}{4} t^2 - \frac{3}{4} t$$
with roots $0, \frac{1}{4}( 3 \pm \sqrt{33})$.  Therefore

$$\max_{(a,b,c)\ne (0,0,0)} \frac{b(c+a)}{ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b+c)}= \frac{1}{4}(3 + \sqrt{33})$$

Note that  $\frac{1}{4}(3 + \sqrt{33}) < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 - \sqrt{2}}$.

$\bf{Added:}$ We can get the upper bound from the OP as follows:  maximize $\frac{b(a+c)}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$, then $\frac{a^2+b^2 + c^2}{ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b+c)}$ and take the product to get the result. This in fact quite simple.

$$a^2 +b^2 + c^2 \ge b^2 + \frac{(a+c)^2}{2} \ge 2 b \cdot \frac{a+c}{\sqrt{2}}$$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{b(a+c)}{a^2+b^2+c^2} &\le &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b+c)} &\le &\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}
so by multiplication
$$\frac{b(a+c)}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b+c)} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2- \sqrt{2}}$$

Now the inequality is strict because the above inequalities are not satisfied simultaneously.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let us prove "by hand" that we have the inequality

$$\frac{1}{4}(3 + \sqrt{33})\ge \frac{b(a+c)}{ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -a(b+c)}$$
indeed LHS $-$ RHS is a positive multiple of
$$(3 + \sqrt{33})a^2 - [ (7 + \sqrt{33}) b + (3 +\sqrt{33})c]\cdot a + [ (3+\sqrt{33})(b^2+c^2) - 4 bc] $$
which has discriminant in $a$ a negative multiple of
$$(16 b -3(1 + \sqrt{33})c)^2$$
so the expression is $\ge 0$ with possible equality.

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: There are many proofs. Here is one.

If $b = 0$, clearly the desired inequality is true.

In the following, assume that $b \ne 0$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$b(c + a)(\sqrt 2 - 1) < (\sqrt 2 - 1)\sqrt 2 = 2 - \sqrt 2 $$
or
$$b(c + a)(\sqrt 2 - 1) < a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b + c)$$
or (simply completing the squares in $a$ and then $c$)
$$\frac14(2a - b\sqrt 2 - c)^2 + 
\frac34 \left(c - \frac{3\sqrt 2 - 2}{3}b\right)^2
+ \frac{3\sqrt 2 - 4}{3} b^2 > 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Could you explain more about how you completed the squares and flipped the sign of the inequality?

Comment: @TiagoCavalcante Since $A < B$ is equivalent to $B > A$. So $b(c + a)(\sqrt 2 - 1) < a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b + c)$ is equivalent to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a(b + c) > b(c + a)(\sqrt 2 - 1)$. The completing procedure is quite common: for example $a^2 + pa + q = (a + p/2)^2 + q - p^2/4$.